# Нужна ли запятая перед „и“?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, союзы

> Я и маму люблю() и отца

Нужна ли запятая на месте скобок? Вроде, по правилам, два однородных члена, соединённые повторяющимся союзом, образующие тесное смысловое единство и не имеющие зависимых слов, запятой не разделяются... Но в этом примере мне видится запятая. Что вы думаете по этому поводу?

Comment: _"образующие тесное смысловое единство"_ - если факт этого единства поставить под вопрос, то запятая появится из-за повторяющегося союза. Я бы тоже поставил запятую.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я и маму люблю, и отца.

Давайте сравним с предложением, где вы вряд ли поставите под сомнение смысловое единство.

Я люблю и мать и отца.

Чем отличаются предложения? Инверсией. Причем такой инверсией, где одно дополнение «оторвано» от другого. Единство нарушено, дополнения разделяются паузой. Логично поставить запятую.

Comment: Всё гениальное просто!

Answer (score 3):

1. **Вместо вступления (о грамматике  соединительных союзов)**

Вы никогда не задумывались над тем, чем по семантике отличаются соединительные союзы: **повторяющийся союз И…И и одиночный союз И?** Тогда стоит почитать об этом в грамматических справочниках. [http://rusgram.ru/Сочинительные_союзы](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D1%8B)

По сравнению с одиночными союзами, повторяющиеся союзы имеют **два общих семантических свойства.**  В предложении с повторяющимся союзом:

(1) подчеркивается, что **каждый** конъюнкт (однородный член или  предложение) **участвует** в сочинении;   (2) каждый конъюнкт рассматривается **отдельно.**

Тогда согласно свойству (1) употребление повторяющегося союза И…И  уместно в том случае, когда имеется **сомнение** относительно истинности какого-то из конъюнктов.

**Когда же возникает сомнение?** Такое возможно, например, при вопросе, когда нам предлагают выбор: ***Ты кого больше любишь, отца или мать?***

Тогда мы отвечаем: *Я обОих люблю, и отца и мАть.*  При отсутствии запятой это закрытый ряд, его дальше не продолжишь.

Или отвечаем так: *Я обОих люблю: и отцА,  и мАть* (и вообще всех родных).  Этот ряд незакрытый, его можно продолжить.

**Грамматика и интонация разные**: это или пояснение местоимения ***обоих***, или однородный ряд  после **обобщающего слова** с перечислительной интонацией.

**А семантика?**  Второй ответ более общего характера, он подходит для вопроса: *Кого из родных ты больше любишь?*

Так что же нам дает **объединение однородных членов** при отсутствии запятой? Это и есть их **тесное смысловое единство**, приближение к значению одного слова, в частности во фразеологических оборотах, например: *и зимой и летом* – круглый год, всегда, *и отца и мать* – обоих.

При отсутствии запятой в какой-то мере **нарушено правило** (2) о самостоятельности однородных членов, так как интонация объединяет их. Получается, что  **повторяющийся** союз по семантике сближен **с одиночным**, а первая часть союза больше напоминает усилительную частицу И.

А если мы ставим запятую, то **такого объединения нет**. Перечислительная интонация позволяет нам продолжить однородный ряд, члены которого самостоятельны, то есть они по отдельности  связаны со сказуемым.

Согласитесь, что **различия** между двумя вариантами довольно существенные – и по интонации, и по семантике.

**2. Ответ**

А теперь вернемся к нашему предложению:  ***Я и маму люблю ( ) и отца.***

Интонационно возможны оба варианта,  **инверсия** дополнения этому не препятствует. Варианты  различаются длительностью пауз и наличием перечислительной интонации при постановке запятой  (там силовое ударение падает на каждый однородный член).

(1)  Я и мАму люблю, и отцА.  (2) Я и мАму люблю //и отцА.

И что тогда делать? **Тесное смысловое единство формулой не выразишь**, а тут еще наши классики (Розенталь, ПАС) высказываются  весьма **неопределенно**: запятая обычно не ставится, может не ставиться.

Получается, что всё зависит **от контекста**: от заданного вопроса,  от смысла, который выражает отвечающий (другими словами, от коммуникативной составляющей данной ситуации).

– *Ты кого больше любишь, маму или отца? – Я и маму люблю и отца.*   Смысл такой: Я люблю обоих.

– *Ты кого больше любишь, маму или отца?  Я и маму люблю, и отца.*  Смысл такой: я не выбираю между родными в своей семье, а люблю их всех.

**3. Вывод**

**Не согласны?** Я так и думала, ведь только всё простое гениально (мы об этом недавно говорили).

Но вот с тем, что данное предложение имеет **две интонационные формы**, всё-таки придется согласиться.

**И неужели это совсем ничего не значит?**

**4. О пояснительных словах**

А как же быть с пояснительными словами, точно ли при их наличии запятая ставится?

Сравним два предложения:

(1) ***Холодными оказались и веснА, и начало лЕта*.** Запятую ставим, обозначая перечислительную интонацию.

(2)  ***Холодными оказались и весна и начало лЕта, а потом вдруг стало очень жАрко.*** Запятую не ставим, так как интонационно надо обозначить противопоставление простых предложений в составе сложного.

Получается, что **от структуры** предложения зависит очень многое, в частности возможность обозначать или не обозначать единство однородных членов. Таким образом, не зря лингвисты **так осторожны** в своих оценках и выводах.