# Об афоризме «всё гениальное просто»

Tags: фразеология, семантика

Не все знают полный текст этого афоризма: **Всё гениальное просто, и всё простое гениально.**

Автором фразы именно в таком формате является **Йозеф Геббельс**. До него данная мысль излагалась и Леонардо да Винчи, и Наполеоном, и в некоторой степени Эйнштейном. **Леонардо да Винчи**: «Простота — это то, что труднее всего на свете; это крайний предел опытности и последнее усилие гения». Этот афоризм, в свою очередь, восходит к древнему изречению «Слова истины просты» **Еврипида**.
https://zen.yandex.ru/media/id/5a993fd7a815f12772fa0e7a/vse-genialnoe-prosto-5a9e8a8c7ddde80b455dbc57

И вот мне кажется, что мы чаще имеем в виду именно вторую часть высказывания: **всё простое гениально.** Но вот эта мысль вызывает у меня сомнение.

**Простой** – это несложный, первичный, примитивный, незамысловатый, обыкновенный. Как же всё это можно считать гениальным? **Простота у гениальности  совсем другая** – это долгий путь к совершенству, озарение, прорыв в информационное пространство – и полученное знание, которое имеет простую формулировку.

Интересен пример, связанный с системой русского правописания, уж очень много желающих ее **упростить**, в то время как она нуждается не в изменении, не в упрощении, а в более глубоком понимании.

Нужно не просто механически применять правила от сих до сих, как это мы делаем (**в такой простоте я не вижу гениальности**), а научиться понимать их смысл. Система перестанет быть сложной, когда будет понятна ее логика. Тогда она покажется нам гениально простой.

**А как вы понимаете этот афоризм**, в каких случаях уместно его применение, а в каких нет?

Примечание. Я вспомнила этот афоризм, прочитав недавнюю запись [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461480/Нужна-ли-запятая-перед-и](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461480/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%B8)

В то же время это **скорее** повод вспомнить изречение, но не сама оценка.

Comment: "Гениальная простота его стиля до сих пор не оценена по достоинству."  К. И. Чуковский. О Чехове // «Нива», 1915

Comment: "Сразу нужно отметить, что Антон Павлович Чехов не имел литературного и гуманитарного образования. Он был писатель-самоучка. Свои таланты он распознал сам, сам научился грамотно владеть слогом и писать выдающиеся тексты."  // А кто из выдающихся писателей имел литературное образование? //  Может,  наоборот,  чем больше учишься, тем хуже пишешь.

Comment: Может, наоборот, чем больше учишься, тем хуже пишешь.) может и так.

Comment: Или смотря кто учителя, насколько знаком с теми у кого учишься.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вторая часть, добавленная этим персонажем, мне представляется *ненужной и неверной*. Обобщение "всё" в этом добавлении опровергатся хотя бы тем, что простой бывает и глупость (даже при допущении сложных её форм).

Выражение "всё гениальное просто" можно понимать в том смысле, что простой на вид полезный результат порой достигается за счёт *оригинального* подхода к научной, технической или военно-стратегической задаче, доступного лишь гению, в то время как нагромождение существующих технологий к этому результату до вмешательства условного гения не приводило. Технологии, примененные по своему назначению, связаны с условно рутинным трудом (проектированием) и приводят к построению *сложных* систем (компьютеров, суперкомпьютеров, космических комплексов и т. п.), которые при всей их сложности гениальными не называют, - это просто результат длительного развития технологии и большого труда многих людей. *Гениальная простота*, противопоставляемая этому выражением "всё гениальное просто", незримо подразумевает такие открытия, как Архимедово, формулу энергии Эйнштейна и т. п.; она не означает простого подхода в нахождении такого решения (за этим стоят труд и оригинальность мышления, без него результат оставался недоступным для предшественников), а указывает на красивый и внешне простой результат. Трубный ключ сантехника (который дополнительно сжимается при повороте) *гениально прост* (как результат изобретения), а суперкомпьютер - нет (не прост и не гениален).

Answer (score 1):

Начнём с того, что фраза сказана Гебельсом, человеком, который профессионально занимался пропагандой. В пропаганде - действительно не работают сложные приёмы, потому что направлена она на толпу, а интеллект толпы крайне невысок. Жириновский сколько угодно может писать удивительные по прозорливости политологические работы (а их у него не мало), но воспринимать его всё равно будут как фрика, подравшегося в думе, так как это проще.

За пределами воздействия на массы людей, верна лишь первая часть, поэтому полную фразу *"Всё гениальное просто, и всё простое гениально. Маленькому человеку нравится скрывать свою ничтожность за сложными вещами"* и мало кто помнит. Однако когда читаешь некоторые книги по педагогике можно согласится и с полным вариантом.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.  Простое может быть гениальным, если по эффективности оно равнозначно сложному или даже превосходит его. Возможно, для убеждения толпы простые приемы действительно предпочтительнее, и в наше время можно с интересом наблюдать за этим. Если же при оценке, к примеру, художественного произведения мне скажут, что только простое гениально, то я вряд ли с этим соглашусь. В этом случае нет заведомо верного ответа или объективного показателя эффективности, как в предыдущем случае.

Comment: @Sharon много ли людей знают кто такой Велимир Хлебников или хотя бы готовы процитировать Маяковского (что-то кроме "Я достаю из широких штанин")? Кстати из последнего если что и вспомнят, так это не новаторские рифмовки и раскрытые метафоры, а очень простое и душевное "Послушайте". 

А вот условного Чуковского помнят, ценят, издают, хотя это шизоидный алогичный бред с первой попавшейся рифмой.

 Так что если мы говорим о воздействии на массы, то чем проще - тем лучше. Ценителям это может наоборот не понравиться, но "пипл схавает".

Comment: Я как раз это и имею в виду. Простой Чуковский  в плане воздействия на массы, безусловно, гениален. Но что-то я замечаю, что современные дети не сильно увлекаются классиками детской литературы. Хотя новые бренды у них  тоже выглядят странно, Так что неизвестно, что еще лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ-комментарий

Александр, **большое спасибо за ваше мнение.** Оно прояснило мне мою собственную точку зрения по поводу первой части афоризма – «всё гениальное просто».

Гениальное, как я думаю, связано с **качественным прорывом** в решении каких-либо задач. Мне кажется, что такой гениальный прорыв нам нужен сейчас  в области **энергетики**. Вокруг  полно скрытой энергии, но мы не можем получить простого и безопасного доступа к ней.  Другая область, где также нужен гений, – это  взаимодействие **материи и сознания**. Там много разных технологий, но все они частного вида, их эффективность носит характер случайного успеха. А вот **компьютеры, даже Интернет** – это действительно **сложные, но не гениальные системы**.

Я, как и вы,  **негативно** отношусь ко второй части афоризма: "всё простое гениально". Это высказывание не только неверное и ненужное, но еще содержит в себе **вредное начало**.  Такое манипулирование путем перестановки позволяет  неверному суждению существовать за счет правильного и маскироваться под правильное, дает ему возможность закрепиться в нашем сознании.

Поэтому надо хорошо понимать, о чем мы говорим, когда используем в нашей речи  фразу "всё гениальное просто" **в качестве дежурной оценки**.

Обычно мы видим простое, которое называем гениальным, и тогда фактически переходим ко второй части афоризма.  Но, может быть, такая оценка является  **девизом** поверхностного и непритязательного мышления?

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд обсуждать Геббельса смысла нет, как уже тут упомянули у него своя специфика и вторая часть и вовсе не имеет смысла.
Я думаю фраза "Всё гениальное просто" существует сама по себе - мало кто знает кто и когда её использорвал впервые.
И смысл её вполне понятен - большая часть прорывных идей и изобретений просты сами по себе, когда их знаешь они кажуться очевидными, но ввиду слабости человеческого мышления, для того чтобы первым додуматься до этих идей нужен "гениальный" ум.

Comment: Ну и конечно это часть массовой культуры, сложные решения слишком сложны и поэтому неизвестны неспециалистам, а простое решение будет растиражировано СМИ, как очередное подтверждение тезиса, так что частично это искажение.